# How to convert time between two dates into percentage to display timeline chart bar data accurately

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, datetime

I am building a horizontal timeline chart where each horizontal bar and its width represent the time span a milestone will take to complete based on a start date and finish date. Each Rectangle behind these bars represent a month within that time span.

I am looking for help solving how to most accurately convert the time between the start and finish date into a % so that I can accurately display that timeline bar on my horizontal scrollable calendar.

My data(dates) will be coming from a JSON object and I was planning on using [data-fns](https://date-fns.org/) for manipulating dates as needed. I am currently using React.js w/Typescript.

If this is confusing at all please don't hesitate to ask me further questions. Thanks for your time!

Here is a screenshot of what the timeline looks like currently. It scrolls left and right on a arrow click in that direction:
[ScreenShot of timeline component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAxKz.png)

Here is a code snippet of my parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import useSmoothScroll from "use-smooth-scroll";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { IconButton } from "office-ui-fabric-react";
import { initializeIcons } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons";
import { ProgressBarCom } from "./ProgressBarCom";
import { Bar } from "./Bar";
initializeIcons();

export const TheSchedule: React.FC = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ];
  const getScrollTarget = (node: any, direction: string): number => {
    if (direction === "right") {
      if (width < node.scrollWidth) {
        setWidth(width + 305);
        return width + 305;
      } else {
        return width;
      }
    } else {
      if (width !== 0) {
        setWidth(width - 305);
        return width - 305;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  };
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const scrollTo = useSmoothScroll("x", ref);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ProgressBarCom />
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginTop: "11rem"
        }}
      >
        <IconButton
          iconProps={{
            iconName: "ChevronLeft",
            styles: {
              root: {
                fontSize: "3.5rem",
                opacity: "30%",
                selectors: {
                  ":hover": {
                    opacity: "100%"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          role="button"
          onClick={() =>
            scrollTo(getScrollTarget(ref.current, "left"), { duration: 800 })
          }
          style={{
            marginTop: "12rem",
            color: "grey",
            position: "relative",
            left: 39
          }}
        />

        <div
          style={{
            //display: "flex",
            overflowX: "hidden",
            width: "75%"
            //margin: "7rem auto"
          }}
          ref={ref}
        >
          <div>
            <div style={{ width: "6000px", display: "flex" }}>
              {months.map((month, index) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      // display: "flex",
                      // flexDirection: "column",
                      //alignItems: "center",
                      background: index % 2 === 0 ? "#EDEBE9" : "#E5E5E5",
                      height: "26.8125rem",
                      width: "15.4375rem",
                      border: "solid .05rem grey"
                    }}
                  >
                    <p
                      style={{
                        borderBottom: "1px solid grey",
                        width: "75%",
                        fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
                        fontSize: ".8rem",
                        lineHeight: "14px",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        fontVariantCaps: "all-small-caps",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        margin: "0 auto"
                        //marginTop: ".5rem"
                      }}
                    >
                      {month}
                    </p>

                    {index === 0 && (
                      <Bar
                        title="BOP"
                        date="2/07"
                        width={119}
                        color="#F78C20"
                      />
                    )}
                    {index === 1 && (
                      <Bar
                        title="ASR"
                        date="3/22"
                        width={259}
                        color="#5F308F"
                      />
                    )}
                    {index === 2 && (
                      <div
                        style={{
                          position: "relative",
                          left: "89%",
                          top: "25%"
                        }}
                      >
                        <Bar
                          title="EMV"
                          date="12/22"
                          width={900}
                          color="#5F308F"
                        />

                        <div
                          style={{
                            display: "flex",
                            position: "relative",
                            left: "47%",
                            top: "88%"
                          }}
                        >
                          <label>EV1</label>
                          <span
                            className="dot"
                            style={{
                              margin: ".35rem 0 0 .3rem",
                              height: "8px",
                              width: " 8px",
                              backgroundColor: "black",
                              borderRadius: "95%",
                              display: "inline-block"
                            }}
                          ></span>
                          <div
                            style={{
                              width: "18rem",
                              //height: "1rem",
                              borderBottom: "black 1px dotted",
                              alignSelf: "center"
                            }}
                          ></div>
                          <span
                            className="dot"
                            style={{
                              margin: ".35rem 0 0 .1rem",
                              height: "8px",
                              width: " 8px",
                              backgroundColor: "black",
                              borderRadius: "95%",
                              display: "inline-block"
                            }}
                          ></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <IconButton
          iconProps={{
            iconName: "ChevronRight",
            styles: {
              root: {
                fontSize: "3.5rem",
                opacity: "30%",
                selectors: {
                  ":hover": {
                    opacity: "100%"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          role="button"
          onClick={() =>
            scrollTo(getScrollTarget(ref.current, "right"), { duration: 800 })
          }
          style={{
            marginTop: "12rem",
            color: "grey",
            position: "relative",
            right: 39
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp might help you discover some ways to avoid hard-coding your own list of months and try the script right in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

All dates in javascript are currently stored as seconds since January 1,1970 or so.  Subtract (end date - start date) total seconds.  If you have a date in the range of start to end, the percentage should be (date - start) / totalSeconds.

I'm not a javascript expert so convert to floating point etc. as the language supports it.

Comment: The date time value is milliseconds, not seconds. To express a date as a percentage of a range, the forumula is`100 * (date - rangeStart) / (rangeEnd - rangeStart)`.

Comment: What if instead of going by percent I went by 365.35px month wide divs?